# Moment of Inertia of a gyroscope

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, gyroscopes

I saw that the moment of inertia could be calculated for bodies as the addition of the sum of their parts, so I was wondering if it could be calculated for the gyroscope that is pictured below

[image]

I was thinking that I would weigh the gyroscope, find the volume of each of its components to find the masses, and then use the formulas for the moment of inertia for cylinders and rods. But I was wondering how I would calculate the moment of inertia of the inside star type shape?

Comment: It looks like a pain in the a....... Plus it is not a rigid object

Comment: If you managed to calculate the moment of inertia, how would you use that info? Would it be worth the effort?

Comment: The depicted gyroscope is not a high performance gyroscope, it's more a bare minimum gyroscope. If you have a high performance gyroscope then I can see a use case for knowing the moment of inertia with high precision, but not with this particular gyroscope.

Comment: The star is made of 6 spokes and 12 other bars. The moment of inertia of a spoke or bar is straightforward. Add them up.

Answer (score 0):

For this question,first, you have to calculate the moment of inertia of each rod concerning one side of the the rod at the trisection of rods and spokes
then use parallel shifting for which you have to add mass*(distance between trisection and center)^2 to each trisection and them all up.
other thing are easy to calculate , but make sure to find inertias with respect to a common axis of rotation